# Open files with other apps in webview

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview

I'm building a simple app, in which I use a webview in Android Studio, in the app, i search a movie, and then I download the torrent.

When I download in the web, it automatically send me to the utorrent app, but when I download it from my app, I can't open it.

Sorry for my English and for my poor knowledge.

My java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

WebView web;
EditText et_peli;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    web=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.web);
    et_peli=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_peli);
}

public void buscar0nclick(View v){
    WebSettings conf = web.getSettings();
    conf.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    web.loadUrl("http://www.miltorrents.com/?pTit=" + et_peli.getText().toString());
    web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                                    String description, String failingUrl) {
            Log.d("WEB_VIEW_TEST", "error code:" + errorCode + " - " + description);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            if (url.endsWith(".torrent")) {
                Uri source = Uri.parse(url);

                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(source);

                request.setDescription("Description for the DownloadManager Bar");
                request.setTitle("YourApp");

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                }


                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "SmartPigs.apk");

                DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                manager.enqueue(request);
            }


            else view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure I have this right, you want to send your user, once they download the torrent to the torrent's app to view the movie, correct?

I would check to see if that torrent app has a broadcast receiver that you can search for.  If so, you could just pass along the information.  If not, you have to look for a way to have that media file play within your app, or use one of the default movie players.

Comment: The thing is that when I try to open it in my regular browser my phone asks to open it with another app or it start a download, so I can open it afterwards, but in my WebView app, when I try to open it, it says: "The file can't be opened" @AndroidDev21921